# MongoDB GridFS services on cloudfoundry

Tags: cloud-foundry

we use MongoDB GridFS pluging to store upload file, it work
But we can upload the beginning, usually can not be upload to upload 8M ?

check status in mongodb, they create two collection

```
db.fs.chunks 
db.fs.files
```

type command

> > db.fs.chunks.stats()
>   { 
>           "ns" : "db.fs.chunks", 
>           "count" : 376, 
>           "size" : 84212168, 
>           "avgObjSize" : 223968.53191489363, 
>           "storageSize" : 84250624, 
>           "numExtents" : 8, 
>           "nindexes" : 2, 
>           "lastExtentSize" : 20594688, 
>           "paddingFactor" : 1, 
>           "flags" : 1, 
>           "totalIndexSize" : 49056, 
>           "indexSizes" : { 
>                   "*id*" : 24528, 
>                   "files_id_1_n_1" : 24528 
>           }, 
>           "ok" : 1 
>   }

storageSize is there a limit ?

thank all to help

Todd

Answer (score 1):

the following storage limits are in place on CloudFoundry.com;

```
mysql: 128MB
redis: 16MB
mongo: 240MB
```

It may be that the connection is timing out when actually uploading the data, what actually happens when you are trying to perform the upload?